# Efficient column indexing and selection in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm looking for the most efficient way to select multiple columns from a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,8), columns = list('abcdefgh'))
```

[image: result of code above]

I want to select columns the following columns a,c,e,f,g only, which can be done by using indexing:

```
df.ix[:,[0,2,4,5,6]]
```

For a large data frame of many columns, this seems an inefficient method and I would much rather specify consecutive column indexes by range, if at all possible, but attempts such as the following, both throw up syntax errors:

```
df.ix[:,[0,2,4:6]]
```

or

```
df.ix[:,[0,2,[4:6]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `range`:

```
print [0,2] + range(4,7)
[0, 2, 4, 5, 6]


print df.ix[:, [0,2] + range(4,7)]
          a         c         e         f         g
0  0.278231  0.192650  0.653491  0.944689  0.663457
1  0.416367  0.477074  0.582187  0.730247  0.946496
2  0.396906  0.877941  0.774960  0.057290  0.556719
3  0.119685  0.211581  0.526096  0.213282  0.492261
```

Comment: Excellent, your answer has also led me to discover more about the flexibility of the 'range' command!    http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you select non adjacent columns, you will pay the load.
If your data is homogeneous, falling back to numpy give you notable improvement.

```
In [147]: %timeit df[['a','c','e','f','g']]
          %timeit df.values[:,[0,2,4,5,6]]
          %timeit df.ix[:,[0,2,4,5,6]]
          %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.values[:,[0,2,4,5,6]],columns=df.columns[[0,2,4,5,6]])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.67 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.7 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop 
1000 loops, best of 3: 568 µs per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas is relatively well thought, the shortest way is the most efficient:

```
df[['a','c','e','f','g']]
```

You don't need ix, as it will do a search in your data, but for that you obviously need the names of the columns.

Comment: From pandas docs : Note The Python and NumPy indexing operators [] and attribute operator . provide quick and easy access to pandas data structures across a wide range of use cases. This makes interactive work intuitive, as there’s little new to learn if you already know how to deal with Python dictionaries and NumPy arrays. However, since the type of the data to be accessed isn’t known in advance, directly using standard operators has some optimization limits. For production code, we recommended that you take advantage of the optimized pandas data access methods exposed in this chapter.